# Conversion of ionic3 to apk build

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am a newbie to Ionic 3. I have done an application and tried to convert to apk.

> I have done the following process. 1) Ionic cordova build android
>   --release.

After this step it is generating error.[This is  the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BerYE.png)

Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: you need to run the command in your **project directory** _not_ in your platform/../outputs directory. Also, the command is `ionic cordova build android --prod --release`

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to move to the **project's root directory** and then:

You can generate debug (or testing) `android-debug.apk` using below `CLI`

```
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

This is needed for app store release mode build

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Comment: The real issue is OP is running the command in the android platform folder. This is a typo

Comment: Oh.. Updated. Thanks :) @SurajRao

Comment: @Sampath, Sir can you come to team viewer so that it can be very helpfull.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the problem now you have?

Comment: OK tell me your `TeamViewer` id?

Comment: @Sampath, here is my team viewer id 590287604  and password 5177

Comment: It says TeamViewer is not running on your pc? Generate new id.

Comment: @Sampath, sir try with this id 590 286 794

Comment: password is 5177

Answer (score 3):

Use the following steps to generate android signed apk.

1. Generate a release build using following command,
   **ionic cordova build android --release --prod**
2. Go to the apk path using,
   **cd platforms/android/build/outputs/apk**
3. Generate private key using following keytool command,
   **keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000**
   (Replace `my-release-key` with your app name and `alias_name` with key name (e.g myappkey))
4. Sign the unsigned APK, by running the jarsigner.
   **jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk alias_name**
   (Replace `my-release-key` with your app name and `alias_name` with key name (e.g myappkey))
5. Copy zipalign tool from `/path/to/Android/sdk/build-tools/VERSION/zipalign` to `platforms/android/build/outputs/apk`.
6. Run zip align tool to optimize the APK.
   **zipalign -v 4 android-release-unsigned.apk app_name.apk**
   (Replace `app_name` with your app name)

   This will generate **signed** apk.

Comment: Thank you. Nice explanation step by step. Really helpful.